# Change leading / line height in EditText at a character level

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, spannablestring

I have implemented bold, big, non-editable "smart quotes" at the start and the end of my EditText:

[image]

Quotes are a non-selectable part of the text, on which I set a `RelativeSizeSpan(2f)`. The result is pretty much what I wanted.

```
s.setSpan(spanLeft, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
s.setSpan(spanRight, s.length() - 1, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

However as you can see having a bigger font size results in a bigger height that affects the whole line. This is somehow irrelevant on the very first line, but displeasing on the very last. I was wondering if it is possible, for those two characters, to keep the font size but reduce the line height.

[image]

I want to reduce the *leading* part, so that first and last line have a consistent height with the rest of the paragraph. My highest desire would be for the quotes to kind of translate to the baseline while keeping their appearance.

Do you have any suggestion? Is this possible through some `Span` out there? Should I give up? Do you see any workaround?

I see I could create two pngs with the quotes and use `ImageSpan` (though I never used it and don't know how that would work), but it's kind of annoying for me (I'm not really into graphics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you have to implement your custom Span, just leaving the updateMeasureState empty :)
Try with

```
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.MetricAffectingSpan;

public class TestSubScriptSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan {

    private final float mProportion;

    public TestSubScriptSpan(float proportion) {
        mProportion = proportion;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint p) {
        // DO NOTHING!
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
        tp.setTextSize(tp.getTextSize() * mProportion);
        tp.baselineShift -= (int) (tp.ascent() / 2);
    }
}
```

and then

```
TestSubScriptSpan tss = new TestSubScriptSpan(2.0f);
s.setSpan(tss, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
s.setSpan(tss, s.length() - 1, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Pay attention to the order of what you do inside the updateDrawState(), since it's important.

Comment: This solution has some issues with horizontal measurement. It happens that the last character gets trimmed, because it’s bigger than what the span believes it to be. To avoid this you should put `tp.setTextScaleX(mProportion)` in the `updateMeasureState`.

Answer (score 0):

I created a similar effect in one of my apps, where I had a span that made the spanned text smaller, and made it stick to the x-height of the main text, off the baseline. I created a custom span that extends `MetricAffectingSpan` and implements the baseline shift. I used [`SuperscriptSpan.java`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/e942b4596a12685cb722ddef4e59e279e6fd513f/core/java/android/text/style/SuperscriptSpan.java) from the Android SDK as my example.

The idea in this case is that you pull down the baseline of the big end quote, to make the total lineheight lower. I'm not 100% sure this will work, because I don't know how "clever" the line height calculation is.

If it works, be sure to test it on multiple screen densities. I had to make a `float` fit an `int` somewhere in there, which introduced a rounding error that was so visible on some densities we had to correct for it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am new to text metrics and feel a bit lost; to begin I just tried to use SuperscriptSpan with the only difference that I'm giving  `tp.baselineShift` a hardcoded value (50). However, while the baseline is really shifting to the bottom, the top line is still the same (thus giving an even higher leading). Hope this is clear, and hope you have some guidance :-)

Comment: I was afraid that might happen, the answer was a bit of a bet. I haven't ever tried pushing larger font down, my use case was pushing smaller font up, which is obviously easier. One thing I have found helpful when working with text is to subclass the view, override `onDraw` and just draw lines on the canvas at the baseline, ascent, etc. of the text. That way you can tell what it's measuring.

Comment: I will consider it, right now I think it would be simpler to create two png files  somehow and use ImageSpan . Thank you.